# OpenCL thread occupation

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencl

I wrote a simple OpenCL-raycaster where every thread represents one pixel. Of course, some threads, especially the ones that just show empty void terminate rather quickly compared to other ones. My question is: are the used cores available for other kernels to run after they `return` or do they all get freed after the last of the workgroup or even the entire program is finished?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCL the global work size gets subdivided into a number of workgroups (which can get executed serially or in parallel, up to the implementation, but independently in either case). Workgroup sizes vary (e.g., 32 to 256 item is typical), and you are also allowed to specify the workgroup size. A workgroup doesn't terminate until all threads in the workgroup are done, so heavy processing on one thread combined with light processing on nearby threads can leave idle hardware. However, due to locality (objects versus empty space) this will likely only happen on the boundary of objects. Furthermore, within a workgroup some threads may be grouped together and processed as SIMD, which also means that branching may cause idle hardware (study "thread divergence").